# Is there any way to perform queue operations in ActiveMQ without JMX

Tags: spring, activemq-classic, message-queue, jmx, broker

Currently I am using JMX to do ActiveMQ operations like `purge`, `pause`, `stop`, etc. through JConsole. I would like to do the same without JMX programmatically. I tried to use `BrokerService` of ActiveMQ, but couldn't actually do it.

Can anyone please help me on this? I just want to remove JMX and use the ActiveMQ API itself to perform queue operations.

It would be of great help if anyone can explain with example. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I will not formulate an answer because I am not sure if this will help you, but this looks like what you are asking at the first sight: https://dzone.com/articles/managing-activemq-jmx-apis

Comment: Actually i had asked without using JMX. But the given link is for using JMX programmatically. Thanks..